# Finding intersection point between a line and a plane with a straightedge and compass

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Consider the prismatoid with two parallel bases: a pentagon $ABCDE$ at the bottom and a triangle $A_1B_1C_1$ at the top, placed in a way that the orthogonal projection of the triangle on a pentagon's plane will end up inside the pentagon. See the picture for clearer reference.

[image: A trapezoid ABCDEA1B1C1]

A point $N$ belongs to plane $ABA_1$, and a point $K$ belongs to a plane $AEB_1$. Using straightedge and compass, build a point $J$ where line $KN$ intersects a plane $BCB_1$.

People I've asked are saying it's commonly not that easy to define such intersection points, but nevertheless I am very curious on how to do it for a generalized and complex case like this one is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would have been better to ask this as a comment to [my answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4149398/prismatoid-plane-section-with-straightedge-and-compass/4150855#4150855). Anyway, I posted an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say, in general, you have a plane $PQR$ and a line $AB$ not parallel to $PQR$, and want to find the intersection point $M$ between line and plane.

First of all, we must construct the perpendicular projection $A'$ of $A$ on plane $PQR$. To this end, let $H$ and $K$ be the projections from $A$ to lines $PQ$ and $QR$ respectively (these are standard plane constructions). From $H$ and $K$ draw two lines $HA'$ and $KA'$, on plane $PQR$, perpendicular to $PQ$ and $QR$, meeting at $A'$, which is the desired projection.

Repeat the same procedure to construct the perpendicular projection $B'$ of $B$. The intersection point $M$ is then the intersection point between line $AB$ and line $A'B'$.

[image]

Comment: While the logic behind the construction itself is understandable (it heavily resembles the use of a famous theorem of three perpendiculars), I'd like to ask how to drop a perpendicular from a point to a plane. The axiomatic algorithm for that supposedly simple operation is surprisingly absent in the Internet (all I've seen is algebraic adaptations), so I have no idea how to accurately know where will such perpendicular end up on a plane in the first place, and thus can't really advance in this construction. Hope my question isn't too silly or obvious. Just want to gain rigorous understanding.

Comment: @Rusurano I'm not sure I understand: in my answer above I've just explained "how to drop a perpendicular from a point to a plane". Is there anything not clear in the construction of point $A'$? Or do you have some restrictions not allowing certain constructions?

Comment: Yes, I meant I don't understand how do you 'construct' this point $A'$. It's not like you can draw any line in any direction to make it perpendicular to a plane. Like, why does the point $A'$ gets to be where it is and not in any other position of the plane.

Comment: Update: ...oh, my misread. Sorry. I get it now.

Comment: All right. Anyway, I slightly rephrased the beginning of the second paragraph, to avoid possible misunderstandings.